# What do you call the gesture whereby you rest your palms on the side of your hips?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call the gesture whereby you rest your palms, the front of your fist, or your wrist on the side of your hips?

Kind of like these examples:
[image: Woman with left hand on left hip and sword in right hand.]
[image: Man with hands on hips.]

**Update**: Guess I should've made it clear: I did Google "hands on hips gesture". I didn't get a concrete source to back it up, so I went ask here.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Please avoid
discussion, debate, or giving answers
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the
question,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: And then there's *puts her hands in her back pockets Bette Davis style* [Desolation Row](https://www.bobdylan.com/songs/desolation-row/). [Front pockets?](http://www.bobsboots.com/CDs/cd-b17bette.html). [Betty Davis style](https://ask.metafilter.com/171844/Is-Bette-Davis-Style-Real).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Arms "akimbo" is a term I have heard used referring to two hands on the waist.

From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/akimbo):

> *adjective, adverb*
>
> with hand on hip and elbow bent outward

Comment: I've never heard this before. I only associate the word "akimbo" with "legs". But a quick bit of research confirms you're right, so +1.

Comment: In the OP's first photo, only one arm is akimbo, and I've never heard *arms akimbo* used for just one arm. However, Googling finds a number of hits for *"left [right, one] arm akimbo,"* and the meaning is perfectly clear, so I'd say you should go ahead and use it like this.

Comment: @Chappo This one was easy to check so I did it myself, and it appears to be exactly what I'm looking for. Good pointer from the answer.

Comment: Really? I've only ever hear the second definition ("(of other limbs) flung out widely or haphazardly.") used. This is weird.

Comment: Nice, short, but accurate answer.

Comment: I believe it is derived from "arms in keen bow" meaning "arms keenly bowed" or "arms sharply bent".  I have no proof of that, however.

Comment: @user2168 - that's because most people don't actually know what akimbo means, so mis-use it, badly. "Legs akimbo" would really only be an option for the really advanced yoga expert... feet on hips ;-) People use it to mean 'at wild random angles' which is simply incorrect, though as usage eventually gives rise to new meaning, we're probably stuck with it by now.

Comment: @undefined - If you open the link I edited in, and read enough of the page (it's in there somewhere, I remember seeing it!) you'll find that you are indeed correct.

Comment: As a side note, holding *guns* akimbo means dual wielding them (sometimes with your elbows bent outside). The *Borderlands* franchise makes use of this term.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think you mean: "Legz Akimbo."

Comment: Realistically, it only works with arms. Unless one is a contortionist. I've seen 'Middle English 'a keen bow', 'in a sharp curve'. Much easier with arms than legs.

Answer (score 55):

It's called.... "putting your hands on your hips", or possibly the "hands-on-hips pose".

Google gives me 1.9m hits for ["hands on hips"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hands%20on%20hips%22&rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=O8viW9rrMdmugAa06JCQBA&start=90&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwia9eXMlcLeAhVZF8AKHTQ0BEI4ChDy0wMIeg&biw=767&bih=744).

---

*Notes on the google result:*

- *I've used quote marks, to ensure that the three words appeared in that order with no intervening words*
- *This shows that the three words occur in sequence **very** frequently. This suggests (although unfortunately doesn't prove) that there isn't a widely accepted single word or simpler phrase*
- *Compare for example, a description of a salute, which could be ["hand at head"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hand%20at%20head%22&rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&oq=%22hand%20at%20head%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2527j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), ["hand by head"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hand%20by%20head%22&rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&oq=%22hand%20by%20head%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2375j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or ["hand beside head"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=-UrkW-iKJczOgQbe8rd4&q=%22hand%20beside%20head%22&oq=%22hand%20beside%20head%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...8690.9524.0.10025.6.6.0.0.0.0.81.370.6.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.264...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i10i30k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i13i30k1j33i10k1.0.IS8YLOLuvH8) giving 61000, 19000 and 159 results respectively. These phrases aren't common, because the word "salute" exists and gets used instead.*
- *Because "hands on hips" is simply describing what is being done, rather than being a set phrase, normal resources like dictionaries don't have it as an entry, so these can't be used as evidence to support this answer. I've checked [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=hands%20on%20hips) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hands%20on%20hips).*

Comment: Yeah, just what I need. Googling something, get the exact thing word for word I'm supposed to look for without knowing for sure if it's the thing I'm looking for. I guess I should start putting "Google gives me about 2m hits" in my Wikipedia footnotes from now on. Reminds me of all those times Google searches never failed me.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw - Yep, not the most convincing reference to back me up I suppose! I just couldn't think of any other way to justify it, it's not like the word "akimbo" for which a dictionary is the obvious choice.

Comment: For what it's worth, "hand(s)-on-hip(s)" is definitely the term I would use for this - I think it's in much more common everyday use than "akimbo".

Comment: I think the Google search for "hands on hips" is not really representative -- you wouldn't say that in ordinary speech or writing; rather, it would be "with his hands on his hips", replacing "his" with the appropriate name or pronoun.

Comment: @ajd - Good point. "hands on her hips" adds another 2.9m instances, and "hands on his hips" adds 1.6m. Will edit my answer to include these.

Comment: @AndyT also from google, but a good way to back up word usage is to use ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=akimbo%2C+hands+on+hips&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cakimbo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chands%20on%20hips%3B%2Cc0 Akimbo wins, by the way

Comment: I take it that your intention was scrupulous and genuine, but I'd like to note that my mother tongue isn't English (which is truly polysyllabic, and has words clearly separated by spaces, so Google searches work very well with it). Mine is a rather monosyllabic one, spelling is syllable-based, so I have stumbled on situations where one misplaced division of "words" may end up in a large chunk of results even though I use quotation marks just like anybody else. And as you noted yourself, "hands on hips" is way too on the nose and descriptive to be credible as a valid thing people say.

Comment: I've searched for other things with descriptive keywords, and got these kinds of on-the-nose, yet generic and unverifiable, results, but when I simply asked English speakers, I got very specific, accurate and verifiable answers. So I kinda started to discount these kinds of Google search result. That's why I took issue with your answer at first. That could be something you should keep in mind when deciding to cite Google search results. Google searches are worth considering, but this shouldn't have been a full-fledged answer. A simple comment coulda been just as well appreciated.

Comment: Google's estimates are so far off to be useless. The search linked only returns [195 results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hands+on+hips%22&rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=sy3oW9eYMIifzwKP7rywCg&start=190&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiXvvKauMzeAhWIz1MKHQ83D6Y4qgEQ8tMDCIcB&biw=726&bih=727) for me.

Comment: @Laurel we have all fallen victims of Google's optimistic predictions at one time or another, haven't we? Nevertheless, I feel "hands on hips", and its variant "hands on your hips", which Andy mentions, is still the best answer.

Comment: @Laurel - Try clicking the "repeat the search with omitted results included".

Answer (score 7):

In cricket, if a player stands in this pose (with both hands on hips, like the OP's male example) looking angry or frustrated (because another player has messed up, for example) it's often called a "teapot," from the similar shape of an old fashioned teapot with two handles.

> [**Stuart Clark's teapot**](http://www.espncricinfo.com/engvaus2009/content/image/418667.html?object=345973;dir=next) would have made Glenn McGrath proud

I don't know if that usage has spread elsewhere, though!

Comment: Beat me to it! Just saw this, and was going to answer. Note that sometimes called 'double teapot'

Comment: That's a sugarbowl! :)  A "teapot" needs the other arm held like a spout, as the song indicates.

Comment: @Graham No, what you describe as a " teapot" is a "sprinkler" - but used as a victory dance, not a static pose like the OP's pictures. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFeqH8EGBHE

Comment: @alephzero This could be a cultural thing for English-speaking countries then. I'm referring to a children's song called "I'm a little teapot", which is familiar to all English-speaking people from childhood. Traditionally, teapots have a ***single*** handle and an opposing spout, which is why your answer is incorrect. Samovars  may have two handles, as may teapots designed to aid people with limited grip, but a traditional teapot does not. Anyone familiar with cricket should also know what a teapot looks like. :)

Comment: Of course I know the "teapot song", but I've never heard the distinction between one and two "handles" made with reference to teapotting cricketers.

Comment: @Graham you are right about what a teapot is but the pose is definitely called teapot in cricket. e.g. http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/239756.html

Answer (score 4):

The one with both hands on the hips is sometimes called the "**Wonder Woman (power) pose**", especially in the context of the (now discredited) theory of [power posing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_posing):

> [image: woman with her palms on her hips]
>
> This one has been dubbed the "Wonder Woman" by the media.
> — [Amy Cuddy atTEDGlobal 2012:
> Your body language may shape who you are](https://www.ted.com/talks/amy_cuddy_your_body_language_shapes_who_you_are/up-next)

> That's right, there's a new power pose in town, and it's called the Wonder Woman: hands on hips, feet wide apart, shoulders back, staring confidently forward.
> — [How The Wonder Woman Power Pose Might Actually Help You Get Ahead At Work](https://www.bustle.com/articles/64462-how-the-wonder-woman-power-pose-might-actually-help-you-get-ahead-at-work)

> Out of desperation, I tried a little experiment: I struck a [Wonder Woman-style pose](http://images.nymag.com/guides/everything/posture150112_pose_3_560.jpg) in the middle of the course in a last-ditch effort to perk myself up, mentally and physically.
> — [I Tried "Power Posing" for One Month to See If It Actually Works](https://greatist.com/live/power-poses-what-happened-when-i-tried-it-for-one-month)

> Many of us have turned to the “Wonder Woman” pose during times of stress and anxiety in an effort to exude confidence.
> — ['Wonder Woman' Power Pose Does Not Boost Confidence, Testosterone Levels: 3 Hacks To Appear More Confident](https://www.medicaldaily.com/wonder-woman-power-pose-does-not-boost-confidence-testosterone-levels-3-hacks-405286)

To state it a different way, if you looked up "Wonder Woman" in the dictionary (or, well, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman)), that's the pose you would see. (No, seriously, it's there.)

Comment: Great idea, but to make this work you have to be wearing a funky gold crown-thing, have a red top with two gold birds on your chest, and you should be wearing star-spangled blue shorts and knee-high red boots. And you should be Lynda Carter. Actually, just being Lynda Carter may be enough. Try it and let me know how it works out, Lynda.

Comment: @BobJarvis Laurel didn't say it worked (in fact, she agreed with you and said it was discredited), she just gave a reference for what it was called.  All that said, if you believe it will give you more confidence....  The Placebo Effect is a real thing.

Comment: "Wonder Woman pose" is nice.  I've never heard it used but its meaning is clear.  "Teapot" is also good, but will confuse Americans who see very little soccer,--  er, "football." But these terms should not be confused with "akimbo," which refers only to the position where per dictionary.com one has; "hands on hips and elbows bent outward." "Akimbo" also has a different meaning than the other two suggestions.  It doesn't express a serious reproach like the teapot gesture, nor is it boastful, like the Wonder Woman pose.  It merely express impatience or mild disapproval of the one it's aimed at.

Comment: One last thing.  "Akimbo" usually also connotes that one has not the hands themselves, but rather only the back of one's wrists on one's hips.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard it called "power pose"

> Power posing is a discredited hypothesis in psychology that claims that by assuming a "powerful" posture, subjects can induce positive hormonal and behavioral changes. It was introduced in a 2010 paper by Dana Carney, Amy Cuddy, and Andy Yap.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_posing) The idea has been referred to as pseudoscience

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_posing)

Comment: Actually,  "power pose" is a category of several positions, including the one where you raise your arms above your head and another where your hands are behind your head.

Comment: The expression 'power pose' started in the 1950's and took off in the 1970's.  (*Superman* started posing in 1938).

Answer (score -2):

**The Big Cheese**

Source:
https://www.mariowiki.com/Form_Baton
Scroll down to "The Big Cheese"